# estimate conditional distribution from data

Tags: r, distributions, logistic, kernel-smoothing, splines

I have a dataset defined by 2 variables

```
> head(as.data.frame(d))
   age asthma
1 54.0      1
2 57.0      1
3 42.0      2
4 44.0      1
5 56.6      1
6 58.0      1
> summary(d$asthma)
   1    2 NA's 
6937 1105  876 
>
```

I would like to estimate the density distribution of asthma as a function of age.  So something like `P(asthma==1|age=23) = p`  .

During this estimation I need to take into account that this estimated probability should be a continous function of the age.

In other words `P(asthma==1|age=45) ~ P(asthma==1|age=46)`

I would like to know what is the method that I should use and how to compute it in R with my dataframe.

Ideally I would in the end to generate a plot of the obtained distribution `P(asthma==1|age=x)`

Comment: You need two things: splines and logistic regression.  A great deal about both can be found by searching this site.

Comment: I was thinking something like gam.  But I was wondering if there is anything better

Comment: While framed quite differently, I think this is a possible duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137582/can-one-do-glm-with-loess-transformed-variables/137649#137649 --- actually I am wondering about the feasibility of moving the answer here and closing the other as a duplicate, since I think this one doesn't get distracted by trying to transform the predictors..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logistic regression with the predictor `age` represented as a spline function. The simplest way is to use a regression spline, then you fix the amount of smoothing beforehand, most conveniently by specifying an equivalent degrees of freedom (edf). In R something like:

```r
    library(splines)
    mod0 <- glm( asthma ~ splines::ns(age, df=6), 
                 family=binomial, data=your_data_frame)
```

If you want to let the data determine the degree of smoothing, you can use a `gam` (generalized additive model), in R maybe:

```r
    mod1 <- mgcv::gam( asthma ~ s(age), family=binomial, 
                        data=your_data_frame )
```

Also search this site for similar questions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using splines with df=6 defaults to a 6 order polynomial with no breakpoints. Penalized smoothers would probably be preferred. GAM effectively does this.

Comment: @AdamO: Why do you think so? Wouldn'tit depend also on the number of observations? I should admit that I did not study thoroughly the theory behind `ns` ...

Comment: Because you can simple look at the output from `model.matrix(~ splines::ns(age,df=6), data=your_data_frame)` and see it is parametrized as such

Comment: Thanks, will do!